# current enclosed in amperes law

Tags: electromagnetism

according to the integral form of ampere's law when rate of change of electric flux through surfaces with boundary as amperes loop is zero then the following holds:
∮⋅=
but I don't exactly understand what current enclosed means
some examples include
a) amperian loop is in the xy plane and the current carrying loop with current i is in the yz plane piercing through the area twice
(is the current enclosed zero or i)
b)both are concentric circles in the same plane
also in general how to find current enclosed (apart from these examples)